# Python patch/mock under __name__ == "__main___"

Tags: python, mocking, patch

I have the following file named `w.py`, and under `__name__ == "__main__"`, I want to patch `MyAPI`, running `python w.py` shows the patching is not working at all. Is `patch('common.apis.MyAPI', mock_api)` being used correctly?

```
from common.apis import MyAPI


class Worker:
    def __init__(self):
        companies = MyAPI.all()
        raise Exception(companies)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from mock import patch, Mock

    mock_api = Mock()
    mock_api.all.return_value = {'dummy': 'dummy'}

    with patch('common.apis.MyAPI', mock_api):
        Worker()
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want to patch `MyAPI.all` so that it returns `{'dummy': 'dummy'}`. You can do it as follows:

```py
from common.apis import MyAPI

class Worker:
    def __init__(self):
        companies = MyAPI.all()
        raise Exception(companies)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from unittest.mock import patch, Mock

    def all_dummy():
        return {'dummy': 'dummy'}

    with patch.object(MyAPI, 'all', all_dummy):
        Worker()
```